# Windows Controls or .NET objects as Global Variable in Visual C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, global-variables, global, managed

I'm Writing a C++ Class. 
I want to keep a global variable in System::Windows::Form::Control type or a .NET managed objects.
I want to  process something on this global variable.
But Visual C++ is not allowed this.

Returning Error is:
"global or static variable may not have managed type"

May be this error interest Garbage Collector.

How I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use a non managed type like std::string

Answer (score 0):

For a control, you could store the Handle (HWND) in your global variable and get the control back when you need it.
For other managed objects, I don't know. Do they have an identifier that allows doing the same thing ?